# Error creating managed object for class class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener

Tags: java, struts2, glassfish-3, tiles

```
    [#|2013-08-19T11:00:26.424+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase|_ThreadID=90;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException
: Error creating managed object for class: class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5332)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
```

I am at whit's end.
The application in question deploys fine on glassfish 3.0.2 (with a LOT of apps deployed).
It deploys fine on two different development machines (Glassfish 3.1.2).
So far all running Oracle (SUN) JVMs.
It deploys fine in a OpenSUSE VM, with OpenJDK 1.7, Glassfish 3.1.2.2

On our (all) our production machines, running OpenJDK1.6, Glassfish 3.1.2.2, we get the above problem.

I'm pretty certain this is some library version conflict of some kind, but I do NOT know where to look anymore.

The project pom.xml follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>StrutsTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>StrutsTest</name>

    <properties>
        <struts2.version>2.3.8</struts2.version>
        <struts2-jquery.version>3.5.1</struts2-jquery.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2-jquery.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Velocity -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>struts-tiles</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework </groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework </groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework </groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework </groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework </groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework </groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework </groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-jquery-grid-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.jcsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcsv</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <type>jar</type>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javaee</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <warName>StrutsTest</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.21</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <scanTargets>
                        <scanTarget>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</scanTarget>
                        <scanTarget>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</scanTarget>
                        <scanTarget>src/main/resources/struts.xml</scanTarget>
                    </scanTargets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <terse>false</terse>
                    <echo>true</echo>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <glassfishDirectory>${glassfish.glassfishDirectory}</glassfishDirectory>
                    <user>${glassfish.user}</user>
                    <adminPassword>${glassfish.adminPassword}</adminPassword>
                    <domain>
                        <name>${glassfish.domain.name}</name>
                        <host>${glassfish.domain.host}</host>
                        <adminPort>${glassfish.domain.adminPort}</adminPort>
                    </domain>
                    <components>
                        <component>
                            <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                            <artifact>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.war</artifact>
                        </component>
                    </components>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile >
            <id>local</id>
             <properties>
                <glassfish.glassfishDirectory>/apps/glassfish3</glassfish.glassfishDirectory>
                <glassfish.user>admin</glassfish.user>
                <glassfish.adminPassword>adminadmin</glassfish.adminPassword>
                <glassfish.domain.name>domain1</glassfish.domain.name>
                <glassfish.domain.host>localhost</glassfish.domain.host>
                <glassfish.domain.adminPort>4848</glassfish.domain.adminPort>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Post a complete stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt Roman - the initial problem was precisely that the stack traces from glassfish server log were not very helpful. But the error report from the asadmin deploy attempt (in my answer below) was actually helpful - should have tried that loooong ago. But any case, all seems resolved now. Cheers!

Comment: you can accept your answer later so that if anyone with similar issue happen to land here, they should get indication that this is how we can resolve issue

Comment: Thanks Umesh, I will be sure to that, I think I still have to wait a day. Setting up a reminder to do so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RIGHT, our IT guys tried a deploy form the command line on production. From this we got this:

```
    remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: 
    Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: 
    start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
    javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: CDIExtension not found
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: 
    CDIExtension not foundjava.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: 
//Edited to remove repetive lines
   . Please see server.log for more details.
```

This then lead me to these:

- http://www.imixs.org/roller/ralphsjavablog/entry/glassfish_3_1_x_cdiextension
- https://www.java.net//forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/gf-311-jdk1716-linux-64bit-application-running-windows-7-does-not-deploy-linux
- https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1115

SO, in SHORT, we got it deploying by adding this to the JVM environment properties:

```
-Dcom.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.lookupExtensionInBeanManager=true
```